# module dependencies in prism wpf

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container, modularity

i am trying to code something similar to the project 'Modularity with unity'.
i built 2 modules: Module A (loaded via code) and Module D (loaded from directory).
both are loaded successfully.

but when i try to set dependency it's not working.
i can't really figure out where the dependency is mentioned in this project.
(i set the dependency as attribute in ModuleA class, moduleD is copied after build)
this is my implementation:

Bootstrapper.cs

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    return new AggregateModuleCatalog();
}

protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
{
    base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

    Type moduleAType = typeof(ModuleAModule);
    ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo()
    {
        ModuleName = ModuleNames.ModuleA,
        ModuleType = moduleAType.AssemblyQualifiedName
    });    

    DirectoryModuleCatalog directoryCatalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
    ((AggregateModuleCatalog)ModuleCatalog).AddCatalog(directoryCatalog);
}

protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();

    this.RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IModuleTracker), typeof(ModuleTracker), true);
}
```

ModuleA.cs

```
[Module(ModuleName = ModuleNames.ModuleA)]
[ModuleDependency(ModuleNames.ModuleD)]
public class ModuleAModule : IModule
{
    private ILoggerFacade _logger;
    private IModuleTracker _moduleTracker;

    public ModuleAModule(ILoggerFacade logger, IModuleTracker moduleTracker)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _moduleTracker = moduleTracker;

        _moduleTracker.ModuleConstructed("ModuleA");
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _logger.Log("ModuleA demonstrates logging during Initialize().", Category.Info, Priority.Medium);

        _moduleTracker.ModuleInitialized("ModuleA");
    }
}
```

ModuleD.cs

```
[Module(ModuleName = ModuleNames.ModuleD)]
public class ModuleDModule : IModule
{
    private ILoggerFacade _logger;
    private IModuleTracker _moduleTracker;

    public ModuleDModule(ILoggerFacade logger, IModuleTracker moduleTracker)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _moduleTracker = moduleTracker;

        _moduleTracker.ModuleConstructed("ModuleD");
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _moduleTracker.ModuleInitialized("ModuleD");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps that has something to do with the order in which your modules get loaded? As far as I see Module A gets loaded before ModuleD to which is has a dependency.
Don't know if that does help you but that was my first thought..
Which error message do you get?